# Nmap scan yields: FATAL: Unknown datalink type (127)

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I get an error message trying to scan ports on any remote host using nmap (windows):

```
Starting Nmap 7.25BETA1 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-28 12:36 Jerusalem Daylight Time
NSE: Loaded 138 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 12:36
Completed NSE at 12:36, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 12:36
Completed NSE at 12:36, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 12:36
Scanning google.com (216.58.213.110) [4 ports]
FATAL:  Unknown datalink type (127). Caplen: 0; Packet:

"telnet google.com 80" works fine.
```

Any ideas? Googled but couldn't find any information regarding this..

Answer (score 0):

What options did you choose in Npcap's installation wizard? I think you have selected `Support raw 802.11 traffic (and monitor mode) for wireless adapters`, and then used Nmap to scan on a wirelress adapter, right?

I have to say Nmap currently doesn't support the raw 802.11 traffic mode. So you get that error. You have to re-install Npcap without selecting that option. Then you can scan normally.